# Serialization rule is not working properly in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

The SonarQube Rule "Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable" is not working properly. I have a very compliant example as mentioned in their rules definition like below, but still it is reported as an issue. I found that there was a bug alreeady raised for this (https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-917) and is resolved. And I have the latest version which has this fix as well, but still it is an issue. can some one help me how to resolve this?

`public class Address implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2405172041950251807L;
}

public class Person implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1905122041950251207L;

private String name;
  private Address address;
}`

Comment: Do you run your analysis with maven ? How do you provide bytecode to the analysis ?

Comment: I ran analysis using the sonarqube runner (downloaded from sonarqube wesite and configured it for my project and ran the sonar-runner.bat). Does that help?

Comment: Then do you provide bytecode to the analysis via sonar.java.binaries property?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand your question. My best guess would be you are asking how the SonarQube server knows of the project I am trying to analyze? If that is your question, then i have configured my project as mentioned here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation